# QGIS Mutually exclusive legend within a shapefile

Tags: qgis, symbology, legend

I have a shapefile with 30 different categories/symbols which I would like to make mutually exclusive. I am able to make the shapefile itself mutually exclusive by adding it to a group, but not the symbols within. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: could you give an exemple of the categories in your shapefile?

Comment: Hi Leo, you helped me out yesterday with making a heat map from the rule based style. The categories for example are a range of crops e.g.: corn, beans, carrots, and they are then given values such as yield which are displayed in polygons. I want to make it so when I click carrots the corn and beans aren't selected etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can create one categorie by crop (for example) in your categorized styles:

1. carrots- rule: "crop" = 'carrots'; style> orange polygons
2. beans - rule:  "crop" = 'beans'; style> red polygons
3. corn - rule:  "crop" = 'corn'; style> yellow polygons

by hiding 'beans' and 'carrots" in the layer panel, you will be able to select all 'corn' polygons.

Once selected, you can eventually export the selected entities, or filter the table by showing only selected entities.